# I am trying to run a simple flask application but i am having a TypeError

Tags: python, flask, python-3.7

I am trying to run a simple flask application in which it only prints hello world but i am having a type error. In the type error there is a trackback which is specifying a file named app.py and showing errors in it but i can't figure them out. The file in which i am having error is in the flask folder.Please help me that how i can resolve this problem.

I have already done running these code due to which the command prompt gives me the localhost code but when i tried to run it on the browser i am having the type error .

```
set FLASK_ENV=development

set FLASK_APP=app.py
```

**This is my code**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("__name__")

@app.route("/")

def index():

    print("Hello World")
```

**When i run these three lines on my command prompt**

```
set FLASK_ENV=development

set FLASK_APP=app.py

flask run
```

**i receive this **

- Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
- Environment: development
- Debug mode: on
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 179-513-092
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

**after this when i use the code in my browser the browser shows me this**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-       32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-   32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1967, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "c:\users\muhammad umar\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    "The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to print the response, you need to return it, so that Flask can send it to the browser:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("__name__")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World"
```

This is not to say that you cannot print, you can (it shows up in the console), but remember to return a response in your routes.

Comment: Documentation is a good start. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to 'print' the output but need to 'return' it. So changed code will be :

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("__name__")

@app.route("/")

def index():

    return "Hello World"
```